# Extracting multipart/form-data values in a wso2 gateway written in java using org.wso2.micro.gateway.interceptor.Request class

Tags: java, wso2

I have an existing implementation of wso2 interceptor in java,but not sure how ishould extract multipart request contents.

```
package org.mgw.interceptor;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.wso2.micro.gateway.interceptor.Caller;
import org.wso2.micro.gateway.interceptor.Interceptor;
import org.wso2.micro.gateway.interceptor.InterceptorException;
import org.wso2.micro.gateway.interceptor.Request;
import org.wso2.micro.gateway.interceptor.Response;

public class SampleInterceptor implements Interceptor {
     public static String value="json";
     public boolean interceptRequest(Caller caller, Request request) {
          boolean hasApiKey = request.hasHeader("X-API-KEY");
          if (!hasApiKey) {
              Response response = new Response();
              JSONObject responsePayload = new JSONObject().put("error", "Missing required header");
              response.setResponseCode(400);
              response.setJsonPayload(responsePayload);
              caller.respond(response);
              // If we respond from the interceptor it is necessary to set the return value as false. 
              // Otherwise the usual request flow will continue.
              return false; 
          }
          return true;
     }
     public boolean interceptResponse(Caller caller, Response response) {
          // Send a custom json message if the response contains the key "error"
          try {
               JSONObject responseObject = response.getJsonPayload();
               if(responseObject.has("error")){
                   JSONObject customErrorMessage = new JSONObject().put("error", "Invalid json payload returned");
                   response.setJsonPayload(customErrorMessage);
          }
          } catch (InterceptorException e) {
               System.out.println("Error while getting the response payload");
          }
          return true;
     } 
}
```

How do i extract form-data parameters from the Request class. Any ideas of methods to be used or relative approach to achieve this.wso2